# ls: how to display directory + filename on each line

Tags: bash, unix, ls

I have a directory with a lot of subdirectories, and I want to list all its files with a certain extension on each line, including the (sub)directory they're in. I'm now using:

```
ls /home/directory -R | grep ".ext" > files.txt
```

That does not give me the output I'm looking for...
Ideally I would like an output that looks something like this:

```
/home/directory/subdirectory1/file1.ext               4.3Mb
/home/directory/subdirectory1/subsubdir1/file2.ext    3.3Mb
/home/directory/subdirectory2/file3.ext               4.6Mb
/home/directory/subdirectory3/file4.ext               5.2Mb
... etc
```

Or even better, with the directories and the filenames in separate columns:

```
/home/directory/subdirectory1/               file1.ext    4.3Mb
/home/directory/subdirectory1/subsubdir1/    file2.ext    3.3Mb
/home/directory/subdirectory2/               file3.ext    4.6Mb
/home/directory/subdirectory3/               file4.ext    5.2Mb
... etc
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Many thanks!

Comment: looks like you want to get the output of `du`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find putty -type f -name '*.c' -printf "%h\t%f\t%s\n" | column -t`

Will produce something like this

```
putty          sshzlib.c   38615
putty          notiming.c  584
putty/charset  macenc.c    7129
putty/charset  sbcs.c      1190
```

If you want the entire path, present your directory argument to find as an absolute directory path from root.